# Is it possible to selectively suppress a post_save (or other) signal in Django?

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm wondering whether it's possible to selectively suppress a Django signal (such as `post_save` or `post_init`) on object creation, or, alternatively, send it certain parameters.

What I have is a `User` object, which can be created in many different ways and places in my code. So to automatically assign a custom `Profile` object to each `User`, I use the `post_save` signal. However, in one specific case, there is extra information that I want to bind to the created `Profile` object. Passing it as arguments to the `post_save` signal would be great, but it doesn't look possible.

The other option is to manually create the `Profile` object, but then I need to that after the `User` is saved, otherwise the `Profile` cannot be bound to a `User` instance. Saving the `User` instance, however, results in another `Profile` being created via the function called by the signal.

And I can't just get the just-created `Profile` object, since that results in  a `'Profile' object is unsubscriptable` error. Any advice?

**Update:**

Here is an example of a possible situation:

```
def createUserProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:  
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    if extra_param:
        profile.extra_param = extra_param
    profile.save()

post_save.connect(createUserProfile, sender=User)

def signup(request):
   ...
   extra_param = 'param'
   user.save()
```

How do I get the variable `extra_param` in the `signup` method to the createUserProfile method, where it is to be stored as part of the `Profile` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this doesn't work for you?

```
user = User(...)
user.save()
# profile has been created transparently by post_save event
profile = user.profile
profile.extra_stuff = '...'
profile.save()
```

If you are obsessed with parameters passing to event, possible but evil:

```
user = User()
user._evil_extra_args = { ... }
user.save()

In event:
extra_args = getattr(user, '_evil_extra_args', False)
```

It is evil because people who will read your code will have no idea what the heck those _evil_extra_args is for and how does it work.

Comment: I went with the evil option in the end, since the first one gives some sort of concurrency error (the db object is still locked from the `save()` event when I try to access the profile).

Answer (score 0):

Delaying `post_save` is not possible (unless you want to [entirely disconnect it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209159/disconnect-signals-for-models-and-reconnect-in-django)), but neither is it necessary. Passing a parameter to the profile is not a problem at all:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    other = models.SomeField()

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, other_param=None, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
       profile.other(other_param) # or whatever
       profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, other_param=p)
```

Comment: What if I want to send that parameter only in one case, and the `post_save.connect` is defined somewhere other than the function creating the `User` object itself? How would that work?

Comment: I think one of us is misunderstanding the other, so I added an example to my question that will hopefully clarify the problem.