# Django call method after object save with new instance

Tags: django, django-models, signals

I want to call a method after this object (in this example `Question`) is saved.
This is what I got:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...

    def after_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        some_method(instance)

post_save.connect(Question.after_save, sender=Question)
```

It kind of works. But the problem is that the `instance` data is the old one (same as before the save). So `some_method(instance)` gets the old `instance`.
But I need the instance with the new data.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The method you call from post_save signal should be outside of the Model. You can put the method inside the models.py or in another file such as signals.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    def some_method(self):
        return "hello"

def question_saved(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.some_method()

post_save.connect(question_saved, sender=Question)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Does the signal not run? Does it not call the model method properly? Have you seen posts such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014411/django-post-save-signal-implementation

Comment: Note that you ll have to add "from django.db.models.signals import post_save" at the top of your file for this to work

Answer (score 1):

You can override save method, and call what ever you want after the object gets saved

Here is a related link: [Django. Override save for model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-override-save-for-model)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something called signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/.
Some operations send a signals before and after they're completed successfully. In the docs you can find a list of built-in signals. You can also create custom signals. For example assume that I want to do something specific each time a new user is created. Then my code would be something like this:

```
users/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

###############
# Recieve the signals and get the signals that are sent
# after models are saved and whose sender is CustomUser
###############
@receiver(post_save, sender='CustomUser')
def do_something():
    do_something_specific
```

You can also save your signals in a separate file called signals.py but you need to change your app's apps:

```
<appname>/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = <appname>

    def ready(self):
        import <appname>.signals
```