# Create dynamically a model in the save() method from another model

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I want to create a model within the save method of another model, so the one generated dynamically is named with a field from the static model.

**Model Code:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        attrs = {
            'piece': models.CharField(max_length=128),
            '__module__': 'myapp.models'
        }
        model = type('%s_piece' % self.name, (models.Model,), attrs)
        admin.site.register(model)
        super(Car, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The model is generated but I don't know how to make the migrations or migrate it to the database.

I tried to migrate it with:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('makemigrations')
call_command('migrate')
```

But I get an error as I'm executing this in an atomic transaction.

Comment: Why would you do this? What's the point? How would you go about referencing this new model outside that method? Really, don't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the problem is I have a huge amount of pieces to put them all in a single model, so I wanted to split them by car model

Comment: I tried and worked fine. Can you give a sample generated model? and which error show

Comment: you can do it by post_save() signal refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014411/django-post-save-signal-implementation

Comment: You can generate the migrations, but once you leave that `save` method `model` goes out of scope. Now you have no way of referencing that attribute; the generated class just disappears. So what's the point?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman how did you migrate the model into the database

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I get that, so how would you store the pieces? All into the same model will make the load really slow...

Comment: Why would it be slow? If you have a Piece model with a ForeignKey to Car, each car would only load the pieces that belonged to it.