# Django - saving one model during saving another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to creaet records in model Tabel after creation moden Vacation. I have Employee who creates a vacation and each date from the duration of vacation has to go to model Tabel.

```
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length = 20) 
    last_name = models.CharField('Last name', max_length = 20) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name

class Vacation(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    vacation_type = models.ForeignKey(VacationType, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    duration = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

class Tabel(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    date = models.DateField()
    day_type = models.ForeignKey(TabelType, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    late_changes = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

I just start with Django. What shoud I use to update model Tabel after Vacation creation? 
 Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django post\_save() signal implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014411/django-post-save-signal-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you can user Django [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal:

**models.py or signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Vacation)
def create_tabel(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Tabel.objects.create(employee=instance.employee)
```

Another option is to override `Vocation` [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_new = True if not self.id else False
    super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_new:
        Tabel.objects.create(employee=self.employee)
```