# Using signals pre-delete, how to turn it off on some occasions?

Tags: python, django, signals

Using Django: 1.10

### Issue: Turn off `pre_delete` signal and receiver sometimes

I want to use `pre_delete` to delete other related records for a model.

And not call it at certain times even when I do want to delete the main model

### What did I try?

I tried overriding the delete function in the main model `PalletContent` like this:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.auto_delete_line_item = False
    if 'auto_delete_line_item' in kwargs:
        self.auto_delete_line_item = kwargs['auto_delete_line_item']
        del kwargs['auto_delete_line_item']

    return super(PalletContent, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then in the `pre_delete`

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=PalletContent)
def auto_delete_line_item(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.auto_delete_line_item:
        EntryFormHelper.remove_entry_form_line_item_from_pallet_content(
            pallet_content=instance)
        ExitFormHelper.remove_exit_form_line_item_from_pallet_content_if_any(
            pallet_content=instance)
```

And then in the appropriate calls:

I expect this to activate the `pre_delete`: `pallet_content.delete(auto_delete_line_item=True)`

I expect this **not** to activate the `pre_delete`: `pallet.pallet_contents.all().delete()`

What I got back was:

```
 File "/usr/../signals.py", line 31, in auto_delete_line_item
    if instance.auto_delete_line_item:
AttributeError: 'PalletContent' object has no attribute 'auto_delete_line_item'
```

Comment: If you can override the `delete()` method, you could just delete the related objects there, and remove the signal.

Comment: I read that it’s better to use signals rather than override the delete method because bulk delete might not call the override delete method

Comment: If you use `queryset.delete()`, then `self.auto_delete_line_item` isn't going to be set, so you need to change your `auto_delete_line_item` method to handle that. For example, you could use `if getattr(instance, 'auto_delete_line_item', False):` instead of `if instance.auto_delete_line_item:`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But is this the best way to turn off signals occasionally?

Comment: I just realised that ur suggestion also means that if I use queryset to bulk delete and I wish to turn on the signal method  it won’t work. Am I right?

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would allow you to 'turn on' the signal method with the `queryset.delete()` method.

Comment: You’re right I don’t have code like that. I am asking in a general way if there is something that allows turning on or off signal receiver methods on the fly while still able to use queryset or model delete method.

Comment: Have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209159/disconnect-signals-for-models-and-reconnect-in-django). I'm still not convinced that you need signals here. If you need to override `instance.delete()` and `queryset.delete()` to provide a way to disable the signal, then you could just do the work there.